# How to play video from youtube using vouforia sdk in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi i am working on Augmented Reality concept in android,using vouforia sdk am able to play vedios in  vedioplayback sample,in vedioplay back sample app using assets folder  for different target images am playing different videos,but  my problem i need to play different youtube videos for different target images.

```
  public class VideoPlayerHelper implements OnPreparedListener,
                                      OnBufferingUpdateListener,
                                      OnCompletionListener,
                                      OnErrorListener
  {

       public static final int CURRENT_POSITION            = -1;
private MediaPlayer     mMediaPlayer                = null;
private MEDIA_TYPE      mVideoType                  = MEDIA_TYPE.UNKNOWN;
private SurfaceTexture  mSurfaceTexture             = null;
private int             mCurrentBufferingPercentage = 0;
private String          mMovieName                  = "";
private byte            mTextureID                  = 0;
Intent                  mPlayerHelperActivityIntent = null;
private Activity        mParentActivity             = null;
private MEDIA_STATE     mCurrentState               = MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY;
private boolean         mShouldPlayImmediately      = false;
private int             mSeekPosition               = CURRENT_POSITION;
private ReentrantLock   mMediaPlayerLock            = null;
private ReentrantLock   mSurfaceTextureLock         = null;

// This enum declares the possible states a media can have:
public enum MEDIA_STATE
{
    REACHED_END     (0),
    PAUSED          (1),
    STOPPED         (2),
    PLAYING         (3),
    READY           (4),
    NOT_READY       (5),
    ERROR           (6);

    private int type;
    MEDIA_STATE (int i)
    {
        this.type = i;
    }
    public int getNumericType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}

// This enum declares what type of playback we can do, share with the team:
public enum MEDIA_TYPE
{
    ON_TEXTURE              (0),
    FULLSCREEN              (1),
    ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN   (2),
    UNKNOWN                 (3);

    private int type;
    MEDIA_TYPE (int i)
    {
        this.type = i;
    }
    public int getNumericType()
    {
        return type;
    }
}

/** Initializes the VideoPlayerHelper object. */
public boolean init()
{
    mMediaPlayerLock = new ReentrantLock();
    mSurfaceTextureLock = new ReentrantLock();

    return true;
}

/** Deinitializes the VideoPlayerHelper object. */
public boolean deinit()
{
    unload();

    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
        mSurfaceTexture = null;
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();

    return true;
}

/** Loads a movie from a file in the assets folder */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean load(String filename, MEDIA_TYPE requestedType,
    boolean playOnTextureImmediately, int seekPosition)
{
    // If the client requests that we should be able to play ON_TEXTURE,
    // then we need to create a MediaPlayer:

    boolean canBeOnTexture = false;
    boolean canBeFullscreen = false;

    boolean result = false;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();

        // If the media has already been loaded then exit.
        // The client must first call unload() before calling load again:
        if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.READY) || (mMediaPlayer != null))
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Already loaded");
        }
        else
        {
            if (((requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE) ||                        // If the client requests on texture only
                (requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN)) &&             // or on texture with full screen
                (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH))  // and this is an ICS device
            {
                if (mSurfaceTexture == null)
                {
                    DebugLog.LOGD("Can't load file to ON_TEXTURE because the Surface Texture is not ready");
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                        // This example shows how to load the movie from the assets folder of the app
                        // However, if you would like to load the movie from the sdcard or from a network location
                        // simply comment the three lines below
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
                        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                        afd.close();


                        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mMediaPlayer.setSurface(new Surface(mSurfaceTexture));
                        canBeOnTexture = true;
                        mShouldPlayImmediately = playOnTextureImmediately;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        DebugLog.LOGE("Error while creating the MediaPlayer: " + e.toString());

                        mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;
                        mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                        mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    // We need to verify that the file exists
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd = mParentActivity.getAssets().openFd(filename);
                    afd.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    DebugLog.LOGD("File does not exist");
                    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // If the client requests that we should be able to play FULLSCREEN
            // then we need to create a FullscreenPlaybackActivity
            if ((requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN) || (requestedType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN))
            {
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent = new Intent(mParentActivity, FullscreenPlayback.class);
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                canBeFullscreen = true;
            }

            // We store the parameters for further use
            mMovieName = filename;
            mSeekPosition = seekPosition;

            if (canBeFullscreen && canBeOnTexture)  mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN;
            else if (canBeFullscreen) {             mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN; mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.READY; } // If it is pure fullscreen then we're ready otherwise we let the MediaPlayer load first
            else if (canBeOnTexture)                mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE;
            else                                    mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.UNKNOWN;

            result = true;
        }

    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Unloads the currently loaded movie
    After this is called a new load() has to be invoked */
public boolean unload()
{
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not start playback");
            }

            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY;
    mVideoType = MEDIA_TYPE.UNKNOWN;
    return true;
}

/** Indicates whether the movie can be played on a texture */
public boolean isPlayableOnTexture()
{
    if ((mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE) || (mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN))
        return true;

    return false;
}

/** Indicates whether the movie can be played fullscreen */
public boolean isPlayableFullscreen()
{
    if ((mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN) || (mVideoType == MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN))
        return true;

    return false;
}

/** Return the current status of the movie such as Playing, Paused or Not Ready */
MEDIA_STATE getStatus()
{
    return mCurrentState;
}

/** Returns the width of the video frame */
public int getVideoWidth()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video width if it is not playable on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video width if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }

    int result=-1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getVideoWidth();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Returns the height of the video frame */
public int getVideoHeight()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video height if it is not playable on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video height if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }

    int result=-1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getVideoHeight();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Returns the length of the current movie */
public float getLength()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video length if it is not playable on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the video length if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }


    int result=-1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getDuration()/1000;
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}


/** Request a movie to be played either full screen or on texture and at a given position */
public boolean play(boolean fullScreen, int seekPosition)
{
    if (fullScreen)
    {
        // If the play request was for fullscreen playback
        // We check first whether this was requested upon load time
        if (!isPlayableFullscreen())
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot play this video fullscreen, it was not requested on load");
            return false;
        }

        if (isPlayableOnTexture())
        {
            // If it can also play on texture then we forward information such as whether
            // it is currently playing (shouldPlayImmediately) and in which position
            // it was being played previously (currentSeekPosition)

            mMediaPlayerLock.lock();

                if (mMediaPlayer == null)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    return false;
                }

                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("shouldPlayImmediately", true);
                else
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("shouldPlayImmediately", false);

                try
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    DebugLog.LOGE("Could not pause playback");
                }


                if (seekPosition != CURRENT_POSITION)
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", seekPosition);
                else
                    mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

            mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
        }
        else
        {
            // If it cannot play on texture then we set these values to default
            mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", 0);
            mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("shouldPlayImmediately", true);

            if (seekPosition != CURRENT_POSITION)
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", seekPosition);
            else
                mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("currentSeekPosition", 0);
        }

        // We must pass the current playback orientation of the activity
        // and the name of the movie currently being played
        mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("requestedOrientation", mParentActivity.getRequestedOrientation());
        mPlayerHelperActivityIntent.putExtra("movieName", mMovieName);
        mParentActivity.startActivityForResult(mPlayerHelperActivityIntent,1);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the client requested playback on texture
        // we must first verify that it is possible
        if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot play this video on texture, it was either not requested on load or is not supported on this plattform");
            return false;
        }

        if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
        {
            DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot play this video if it is not ready");
            return false;
        }

        mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
            // If the client requests a given position
            if (seekPosition != CURRENT_POSITION)
            {
                try
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(seekPosition);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    DebugLog.LOGE("Could not seek to position");
                }
            }
            else    // If it had reached the end loop it back
            {
                if (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.REACHED_END)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                        DebugLog.LOGE("Could not seek to position");
                    }
                }
            }

            // Then simply start playing
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not start playback");
            }
            mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.PLAYING;

        mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

        return true;
    }
}

/** Pauses the current movie being played */
public boolean pause()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot pause this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot pause this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;

    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                try
                {
                    mMediaPlayer.pause();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                    DebugLog.LOGE("Could not pause playback");
                }
                mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.PAUSED;
                result = true;
            }
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Stops the current movie being played */
public boolean stop()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot stop this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot stop this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;

    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.STOPPED;
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not stop playback");
            }

            result = true;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Tells the VideoPlayerHelper to update the data from the video feed */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public byte updateVideoData()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot update the data of this video since it is not on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    byte result = -1;

    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
        if (mSurfaceTexture != null)
        {
            // Only request an update if currently playing
            if (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.PLAYING)
                mSurfaceTexture.updateTexImage();

            result = mTextureID;
        }
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Moves the movie to the requested seek position */
public boolean seekTo(int position)
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot seek-to on this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot seek-to on this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            try
            {
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
                DebugLog.LOGE("Could not seek to position");
            }
            result = true;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Gets the current seek position */
public int getCurrentPosition()
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the current playback position of this video since it is not on texture");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot get the current playback position of this video if it is not ready");
        return -1;
    }

    int result = -1;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
            result = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/** Sets the volume of the movie to the desired value */
public boolean setVolume(float value)
{
    if (!isPlayableOnTexture())
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot set the volume of this video since it is not on texture");
        return false;
    }

    if ((mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.NOT_READY) || (mCurrentState == MEDIA_STATE.ERROR))
    {
        // DebugLog.LOGD("Cannot set the volume of this video if it is not ready");
        return false;
    }

    boolean result = false;
    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            mMediaPlayer.setVolume(value, value);
            result = true;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();

    return result;
}

/**
 *  The following functions are specific to Android
 *  and will likely not be implemented on other platforms
 */

/** Gets the buffering percentage in case the movie is loaded from network */
public int getCurrentBufferingPercentage()
{
    return mCurrentBufferingPercentage;
}

/** Listener call for buffering */
public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
    //DebugLog.LOGD("onBufferingUpdate " + arg1);

    mMediaPlayerLock.lock();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null)
        {
            if (arg0 == mMediaPlayer)
                mCurrentBufferingPercentage = arg1;
        }
    mMediaPlayerLock.unlock();
}

/** With this we can set the parent activity */
public void setActivity(Activity newActivity)
{
    mParentActivity = newActivity;
}

/** To set a value upon completion */
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // Signal that the video finished playing
    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.REACHED_END;
}

/** Used to set up the surface texture*/
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public boolean setupSurfaceTexture(int nativeTextureID)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    {
        // We create a surface texture where the video can be played
        // We have to give it a texture id of an already created (in native) // OpenGL texture
        mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
            mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(nativeTextureID);
            mTextureID = (byte)nativeTextureID;
        mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();

        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void getSurfaceTextureTransformMatrix(float []mtx)
{
    mSurfaceTextureLock.lock();
        if (mSurfaceTexture != null)
            mSurfaceTexture.getTransformMatrix(mtx);
    mSurfaceTextureLock.unlock();
}

/** This is called when the movie is ready for playback */
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer)
{
    mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.READY;

    // If requested an immediate play
    if (mShouldPlayImmediately)
        play(false, mSeekPosition);

    mSeekPosition = 0;
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

    if (mp == mMediaPlayer)
    {
        String errorDescription;

        switch (what)
        {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                errorDescription = "The video is streamed and its container is not valid for progressive playback";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                errorDescription = "Media server died";
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                errorDescription = "Unspecified media player error";
                break;
            default:
                errorDescription = "Unknown error " + what;
        }

        DebugLog.LOGE("Error while opening the file. Unloading the media player (" + errorDescription + ", " + extra + ")");

        unload();

        mCurrentState = MEDIA_STATE.ERROR;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Loading videos this way is against the Youtube terms of use. I would recommend Google's own android api for youtube found at https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/